# How set max count of visible items (markers or clusters) in visible google map on any zoom level

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Suppose you have many items to show on google map with clustering. I need to limit max count of displaying items on any zoom level of map (clusters and markers) to 10. How can I do it without other elements losing. Do I need to create my logic instead of the standard Algorithm or is there a solution that does not require so much effort?

Is there a way to limit count of max visible items on map with any zoom level?
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. Specifically you need to edit your code, so it'll contain the relevant part to your question. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! Done.

Comment: I deleted code, cause it isn't contain relevant info about my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that is the best solution, but...

```
@Override
    public void onClustersChanged(Set<? extends Cluster<BLPBlip>> clusters) {
        if(clusters.size()>10){
            List<? extends Cluster<BLPBlip>> list = new ArrayList<>(clusters);

            Set<? extends Cluster<BLPBlip>> subSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(list.subList(0, 10));

            super.onClustersChanged(subSet);
        } else{
            super.onClustersChanged(clusters);
        }

    }
```